# Running python code In pycharm, KeyboardInterrupt is not working

Tags: python, pycharm

I want KeyboardInterrupt part run by clicking red button(stop) in Pycharm, but it doesn't work.

I tried it in Anaconda3 prompt, and KeyboardInterrupt worked.
However, when I try it in Pycharm by clicking red button, it doesn't work.

```
import time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(3)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(5)
```

`'Process finished with exit code -1'` pops up and nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you use **try-except**. So when you stop your program it print `5` in your pycharm console.

[image]